# Custom ValidationAttribute not Firing On Invalid Data Razor Views

Tags: c#, jquery, validation, razor, attributes

So I have the following custom attribute:

```
public class YearOrOlderAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
   protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext) 
   {
      if (value == null || (int)value <= DateTime.Now.Year)
      {
         return true;
      }

      return new ValidationResult($"Year must be less than {DateTime.Now.Year}");
}
```

On my view model I have the following:

```
[YearOrOlder(ErrorMessage = "You can't go back to the future!")]
public int? YearInput { get; set; }
```

On in the view I have the following:

```
@Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(model => model.YearInput)
```

I have jquery -> jquery.validate -> jquery.unobtrusivevalidation on the page in that order.

The custom attribute is only hit AFTER the form is submitted, not on blur.  If I do a basic '[Range(1234, 4321)]' attribute, that triggers just fine and the error message shows.  Why isn't my custom attribute being triggered?